# DinD configuration for Gitlab CI with private Docker registry in Sonatype Nexus 3

Tags: docker, gitlab, sonatype, nexus3

I have done a setup of my own **Gitlab(-p 7022:22, 7080:9080), Gitlab Runner(-p 7093:8093), Sonatype Nexus3(Maven, Docker, Helm)(-p 10081:8081, 10082:10082, 10083:10083, 10084:10084)**. **All are running as docker images of their own**. And till `docker build` everything runs great(below code snippets doesn't have `docker build` related code). Problem is, I want to upload the final docker image to my Nexus3 Docker Registry which I am unable to do so.

**My Gitlab Runner config is below**

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "testing dind runner"
  url = "http://192.168.0.250:7080/"    ----> Gitlab git repo external url
  token = "SOME TOKEN"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:19.03.12"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

**My Docker registry in Nexus3 is hosted as below**
Web UI = http://192.168.0.250:10081/ (container internal port is 8081 and exposed to host on 10081)
Docker(Group) = 10084 (exposed as the same port through docker)
Docker(Hosted) = 10082 (exposed as the same port through docker)
Docker(Proxy) = 10083 (exposed as the same port through docker)

**My project CI config is below**

```
image: docker:19.03.12

services:
  - name: docker:19.03.12-dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker login -u nx-uploader -p 1234 192.168.0.250:10082

stages:
  - test docker reg

test-docker:
  stage: test docker reg
  script:
    - docker images
    - docker search httpd
```

I am constantly getting errors as

```
$ docker login -u nx-uploader -p 1234 192.168.0.250:10082
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
error during connect: Post http://docker:2376/v1.40/auth: dial tcp: lookup docker on 192.168.0.1:53: no such host
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Need help/pointers to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have exactly the same issue when running this dind image from the gitlab registry instead of dockerhub

Comment: @frbl do you mean that when you pull the image explicitly from the docker registry this whole thing starts working(same image same version but from docker registry)?

Comment: Yes exactly, we've now changed it back to hub, but it's super annoying because of the ratelimiting @Jayesh

Comment: I am no expert in this. Hence I didn't know that it works with the docker registry but fails with its own registry. I moved to Jenkins and although it doesn't yields step information to GitLab, but much more comfortable to use.